# independent component in another component does not show its own props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

i have TutorDashBoard Component which is child of Tutors component working fine. i used Courses Component in said Component and sent tutorId as props ,to show courses of particular tutor with that tutorId.
but Courses component shows tutor instead of his courses. The courses component works fine outside where tutorId is not sent as props.
here is TutorDashBoard :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Grid, Paper, TableContainer, Table, TableHead, TableRow, TableCell, TableBody, withStyles, ButtonGroup, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Courses from './Courses';
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
    display: 'flex',
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  card: {
    padding:10,
    marginTop:10,
    display: 'flex',
    flex:1,
  },
  cardAction: {
    display: 'block',
    textAlign: 'initial'
  },
  cardMedia: {
    width: 160,
  },
});

export default function TutorDashBoard(props) { 
  const[tutorId,setTutorId]=useState(props.tutorId)
  const[tutor,setTutor]=useState({});

  useEffect(() => {

     setTutor({...props.tutorList.find(x=>x.tutorId==tutorId)}
     )

    }, [tutorId])

  const classes = useStyles();


  return (
    <div>
      <h3>DashBoard</h3>

    <div>
      <Courses tutorId={tutorId}/>

      </div>
    </div>


  );

}
```

here is courses component working fine.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import CourseList from "./CourseList" ;
import CourseTable from "../_helpers/CourseTable";
import CourseDashBoard from "./CourseDashBoard" ;
import usePagination from "./usePagination";
import * as actions from "../_actions/courseActions";
import CourseForm from "./CourseForm";
import { Grid, Paper, TableContainer, Table, TableHead, TableRow, TableCell, TableBody, withStyles, ButtonGroup, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import  { useToasts } from "react-toast-notifications";

  const Courses =(props)=> {
    const[flag,setFlag]=useState("CourseList");
    const[tutorId,setTutorId]=useState(props.tutorId);
    const[myList,setMyList]=useState([]);
      useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchAllCourses()


        }, [])
   //// for registered tutor dashborad
   useEffect(() => {
    if(tutorId){

      setMyList(props.courseList.filter(x=>x.tutorId==tutorId)
        )
     setFlag("CourseDashBoard")
      }


    }, [tutorId])


 const showComp={CourseDashBoard:"CourseDashBoard",CourseList:"CourseList"}


        switch(flag){
       case showComp.CourseDashBoard:
         return( 
          <div>

          <CourseDashBoard
               courseList={myList}

               deleteCourse={props.deleteCourse}
               createCourse={props.createCourse}
               updateCourse={props.updateCourse}
               tutorId={tutorId}

                 /> </div> 

                ); 
         case showComp.CourseList:
           return(
           <div>

        <CourseList
             courseList={props.courseList}

             deleteCourse={props.deleteCourse}
             createCourse={props.createCourse}
             updateCourse={props.updateCourse}
             tutorId={tutorId}

               /> </div> 
                );  
                default:
                  return(
                  <div>
              <p>i am from switch default plz check </p>

               </div>
               );
           }  

    }
    const mapStateToProps= (state) =>({
        courseList:state.course.list


    })
    const mapActionToProps={
        fetchAllCourses:actions.fetchAll,
        deleteCourse:actions.Delete,
        createCourse:actions.create,
        updateCourse:actions.update,
        fetchCourse:actions.fetchById

           }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapActionToProps)(Courses);
```

i think there is problem in following part of courses component .

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if(tutorId){

      setMyList(props.courseList.filter(x=>x.tutorId==tutorId)
        )
     setFlag("CourseDashBoard")
      }


    }, [tutorId])
```

i  wonder why the props of inner component are replaced by outer .thanks in advance for help.

here is screenshot of tutordashboard.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: can we use approach like this to workaround? .             ` <Route path="MyCourses" render={(routeProps)=>(
           <Courses {...routeProps} tutorId={tutorId} />  `

Comment: i think this link help but how to implement ` https://codesandbox.io/s/props-in-component-react-router-g2im5?from-embed=&file=/src/index.js `